# Joomla Restrict folder to user group for downloads - custom

Tags: joomla, permissions, download

Im very stack with this..
I have a membership site set with Akeeba subscriptions. Once a user is logged in, he access to the rest of the article with a Download Link on it. The problem is that the download link its just a public url and have no restrictions.

The file to download is in a directory in the root.

Ive tried lot of plugins and components but no one can restrict folders, only components. Was thinking that with a htacces file to give acces to a usergroups, but seems impossible. A script with restrictewd acces can work, but my problem is the downloadable files are thousands, so I just populate the directory trough an ftp account and then I associate to the article trough a XLS file with fileuplader (freakedout Content Uploader)
Ive tried to set a media folder to restrict access to a user group... but thats also a nightmare... i found only unsolved topics in the joomla forum.. hope this is no my case.

It looks no so complicated... but i think im far away.

Please guys.

Comment: so you want to make the download link only available to those who have a membership subscription?

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using Akeeba Subscriptions why don't you use the [Akeeba Release System](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/16825) as well — while it was originally designed for software distribution it has evolved quite a bit since those days and is our go-to product for access controlled files.

As you can read on the Akeeba ([product info](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-release-system.html), [docs](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/arsdocumentation.html)) site you can restrict files to user groups (e.g. the group you put users in when they take out a subscription). The software also has plugins that work with Akeeba Subscriptions and Akeeba Release System to allow you to control access to the files or sections of articles.

The ARS is open source and free just like AkSubs.

Comment: Yes! Go for this solution! It definitely works.